# Multi-particle systems with different accelerations

Tags: free-body-diagram

While taking a system of multiple bodies under motion, is it possible to take those bodies in a system which have different accelerations? Say there are 3 particles having acceleration along x,y and z axis respectively, is it okay to take these three particles under a system, and will Fnet= massxacceleration would still be valid?

Answer (score 0):

If the 3 bodies are considered to be a single system, then $F=ma$ can be applied to the whole system, where $F$ is the net external force, $m$ is the total mass, and $a$ is the acceleration of the centre of mass.

Due to internal forces the 3 bodies might each have accelerations different from $a$.  If you consider each of the 3 bodies to be a separate system, then $F=ma$ can be applied to each.  Now $F$ is the resultant of all forces acting on this body, including those (due to the other 2 bodies) which were previously classed as internal forces.